# new view under vendor/mail/html not found

Tags: laravel, vendor

I have message.blade.php file under vendor/mail/html and it works correctly. then I want to customize this file and create another view that called "message-with-bg.blade.php" but I get "view not found" error. How to add a new file under vendor/mail/html correctly?

Comment: If you want to add a new view (not one of the standard views) you can add it in the folder `resources/views/mail/html`.  The `resources/views/vendor/mail/html` is only for overwriting default templates.

Answer (score 0):

first, did you run the command below, so that you are editing views inside your resources/views folder and not actual vendor folder? You should never change your actual vendor folder, because changes will be removed the next time you run any composer command, or run the code on different machine.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

After that, you would need to edit the build function inside your Mail class, like:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.message-with-bg');
}
```